# Having problems with the JavaScript/jquery and c# implementation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am following a 3 year old c# course on udemy and am unable to solve the problem regarding the implementation of javascript/jquery code. I am suppose to connect the registration code (via jquery/javascript) with a subscription, however my textbox does not work regardless of the information I insert in it, it is not displaying any text, and it should be displaying different messages such are - Could not register the code., The code was successfully added.
Here is my code:

**RegisterCodeController**:

```
public class RegisterCodeController : Controller
{       
   public async Task<ActionResult> Register(string code)
    {            
        if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userId = HttpContext.GetUserId();
            var registred = await SubscriptionExtension.RegisterUserSubscriptionCode(userId, code);
            if (!registred) throw new ApplicationException();

            return PartialView("_RegisterCodePartial");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**_RegisterCodePartial**:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
<div class="panel panel-primary register-code-panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Register Code</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter code here..." />
        <button class="btn btn-primary input-group-btn" type="button" >Submit
            <h3 class="panel-title">Submit</h3>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger hidden">Could not register code</div> 
</div> 
}
```

**RegisterCode.js**

```
$(function () {
var code = $(".register-code-panel input");

function displayMessage(success, message)
{
    var alert_div = $(".register-code-panel .alert");
    alert_div.txt(message);
    if (success)
        alert_div.removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success');
    else
        alert_div.removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger');

    alert_div.removeClass('hidden');
}

$(".register-code-panel button").click(function (e) {
    $(".register-code-panel .alert").addClass('hidden');
    if (code.val().length == 0)
    {
        displayMessage(false, "Enter a code");
        return;
    }
    $.post('/RegisterCode/Register', { code: code.val() },
        function (data)
        {
            displayMessage(true, "The code was successfully added. /n/r Please reload the page.");
            code.val('');
        }).fail(function (xlr, status, error) {
            displayMessage(false, "Could not register the code.");
        });
});

});
```

Comment: Bit confusing - you show us the the Register action which is called by the ajax request, and returns HTML, but don't use that HTML, yet your js refers to `var code = $(".register-code-panel input");` - how do you load the page initially?  Are you using the output of the `_RegisterCodePartial` anywhere?  Is it loaded via a (different) ajax call?  If so, the culprit is this line: `var code = $(".register-code-panel input");` which is in the wrong place - move it to just before you want to use it.

Comment: Add a `console.log(code.length)` to ensure it's not 0 *when you use it* (ie the line before `if (code.val().length`)

Comment: use partial view in Index view:

Comment: <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 regiger-code-area">
        @Html.Partial("_RegisterCodePartial")
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">

Comment: Ok, so why does 'Register' also return the partial *or* the view - given that it doesn't use either.  If it *did* use one or the other then you'll have problems as you'll need to know somehow if you're getting back the partial or a full page.

Comment: Either way, looking at your code, it looks like `var code = $(".register-code-panel input");` is set too soon and the input it refers to on load either doesn't exist or is being overwritten (so no longer exists)

Comment: just trying to follow the code in course and wrote everything like the instructor, but it does not work - honestly, this level of knowledge is a bit too high for me right now, since I am a beginner in c#, especially in jquery

Comment: Ok, in the browser, press F12 to get to the console (one of the tabs that appears).  In the console, enter: `displayMessage(true, "test")` - does that work?  If not, forget about the ajax part and concentrate on getting that to work.  Check, in the console, `console.log($(".register-code-panel").length)` - that should be 1 (one) if not, then when you call your code, the container/panel doesn't exist.  Repeat this for every selector.

Comment: tnx will try that, will let you know:)

Answer (score 0):

You are making a `POST` request but looking at your controller action method it looks like a `GET`. Thus change your API call `$.post('/RegisterCode/Register', { code: code.val() },` to `$.get('/RegisterCode/Register', { code: code.val() },` probably and use a HTTP verb explicitly in your action method

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(string code)
{ 
}
```

Comment: Why does the action look like a GET to you?  `[HttpGet]` does say "this is a GET action" it says "only allow GET actions" - without this, any verb is allowed.   The URL includes both controller and action so no defaulting based on action name.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had the RegisterCode.css file with the same name as RegisterCode.js file, it seems to me this caused some confusion while retrieving data in the Bundle.config, so I renamed the .js file and now it works!